# Access Append Query - Only add certain types

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database where a user pastes across values from another software into an access table named "NAVImportTable". Upon clicking an update button the following append, update and delete queries are ran to import this data into the table "ProductionOrderLineEnquiry";

**NAVImportAdd**

```
INSERT INTO ProductionOrderLineEnquiry
            (ProdOrderNo,
             ItemNo,
             SalesOrderNo,
             Description,
             ExtraDescription,
             Quantity,
             DueDate,
             ExpectedDeliveryDate,
             ItemWeight,
             Status)
SELECT NAVImportTable.ProdOrderNo,
       NAVImportTable.ItemNo,
       NAVImportTable.SalesOrderNo,
       NAVImportTable.Description,
       NAVImportTable.ExtraDescription,
       NAVImportTable.Quantity,
       NAVImportTable.DueDate,
       NAVImportTable.ExpectedDelivery,
       NAVImportTable.ItemWeight,
       NAVImportTable.Status
FROM   NAVImportTable;
```

**NAVImportUpdate**

```
UPDATE ProductionOrderLineEnquiry AS a
INNER JOIN NAVImportTable         AS e
ON     a.[ProdOrderNo] = e.[ProdOrderNo]
SET    a.Cut = IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', True, False),
       a.Folded = IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', True, False),
       a.Finished = IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', True, False),
       a.NAVComplete = IIF(
                  a.NAVComplete IS NULL,
                  IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', DATE(), ), 
                  a.NAVComplete ),
       a.DueDate = e.DueDate,
       a.ExpectedDeliveryDate = e.ExpectedDelivery,
       a.Status = e.Status;
```

**NAVImportDelete**

```
DELETE *
FROM NAVImportTable;
```

The item number is related to the same number within the table "ImportProductAndTypes", under the heading "No". What this is for is so that when later queries are ran, the product can be assigned its specifications ie the "type" of product that it is.

My question is;

How do I get it so that when the NAVImportAdd is ran it assigns the "Type" from "ImportProductAndTypes" and that anything with the value of "Box" for the "Type" heading is not added to the table "ProductionOrderLineEnquiry".

Comment: This isn't going to work: `IIF(e.Status = 'Finished', DATE(), )` - IIf needs the second argument.

Comment: And to answer the question, just use a JOIN and a WHERE clause. If it isn't that simple, please show `ImportProductAndTypes` , see [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result are always helpful.